# How to convert an int [] Array into a java.sql.Array

Tags: java, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

i'm trying to append some integer values to my database, i have made this prepared statement

```
 stmt = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE domotica.artefatti SET id_sensori = array_append(id_sensori,?) WHERE id=?");
```

I have an integers array like this one:

```
int [] integerarray = {values...};
```

I would like to convert/cast it so that I can do something like this:

```
stmt.setArray(1,correctarray);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a JDBC Array instance through the connection. But that only accepts an `Object[]` so you need to convert your `int[]` array to that:

```java
int[] intlist = {....};
Object[] values = Arrays.stream(intlist).mapToObj(i -> Integer.valueOf(i)).toArray();
Array array = con.createArrayOf("int", values);
pstmt.setArray(1, array);
```

Note that `array_append()` can't be used to append one array to another. You need to use `array_cat()` instead if you pass an array to the PreparedStatement.

Comment: This is mostly true. While JDBC does specify the array must be of objects, the PgJDBC driver does support primitive int arrays. See https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/jdbc/ArrayEncoding.java

Comment: @coladict: but `Connection.createArrayOf()` only accepts `Object[]`